# Get bootstrap css file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm using `Bootstrap 3` in my different projects and I would like to get `cards` from `Bootstrap 4` to my projects. But I don't find where I can pull cards in css format instead of scss format.

It's not a good idea to convert from scss to css to my mind.

Thank you by advance and Happy New Year everybody !

**EDIT :**

I found something in https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css

It seems to be cards in css format isn't it ? I just have to copy/paste to my file and it will be ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card > hr {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.card > .list-group:first-child .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card > .list-group:last-child .list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card-body {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1.25rem;
}

.card-title {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.card-subtitle {
  margin-top: -0.375rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-text:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card-link + .card-link {
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

.card-header {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
}

.card-header + .list-group .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
}

.card-footer {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.card-footer:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-header-tabs {
  margin-right: -0.625rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.75rem;
  margin-left: -0.625rem;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.card-header-pills {
  margin-right: -0.625rem;
  margin-left: -0.625rem;
}

.card-img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1.25rem;
}

.card-img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
  border-top-right-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-img-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-deck {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-deck .card {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-deck {
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
  .card-deck .card {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 0%;
    flex: 1 0 0%;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}

.card-group {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-group > .card {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-group {
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .card-group > .card {
    -ms-flex: 1 0 0%;
    flex: 1 0 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .card-group > .card + .card {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-left: 0;
  }
  .card-group > .card:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group > .card:first-child .card-img-top,
  .card-group > .card:first-child .card-header {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group > .card:first-child .card-img-bottom,
  .card-group > .card:first-child .card-footer {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group > .card:last-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group > .card:last-child .card-img-top,
  .card-group > .card:last-child .card-header {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group > .card:last-child .card-img-bottom,
  .card-group > .card:last-child .card-footer {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group > .card:only-child {
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  .card-group > .card:only-child .card-img-top,
  .card-group > .card:only-child .card-header {
    border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  .card-group > .card:only-child .card-img-bottom,
  .card-group > .card:only-child .card-footer {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  .card-group > .card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .card-group > .card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) .card-img-top,
  .card-group > .card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) .card-img-bottom,
  .card-group > .card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) .card-header,
  .card-group > .card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) .card-footer {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

.card-columns .card {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .card-columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
    column-gap: 1.25rem;
    orphans: 1;
    widows: 1;
  }
  .card-columns .card {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.accordion .card {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion .card:not(:first-of-type) .card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.accordion .card:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.accordion .card:first-of-type {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.accordion .card:last-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.accordion .card .card-header {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Yes it was I found. I assume it's ok to insert this part into my Boostrap 3 css file.

Comment: My suggestion is to insert in a separate file instead of adding it in the bootstrap.css file.

Comment: Ok I do that ! Thank you :)